# scrollTop(); animation issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm at a complete loss here.  I'll provide what I currently have below, but for some reason, every iteration I try, something goes wrong...either the animation of scroll doesn't work but the other functions work, the animation of scroll does work but other functions do not work, all doesn't work, or all does work but animation flickers...

I tried to comment everything the best I could and have gotten to a point where if I use `return false;` either in 1 location or another, part of the entire function works, as mentioned above.

In a nut-shell, I'm trying to create an if/else statement that allows for scrolling animation as well as other functions to run all by clicking (1) single div.  This div, aside from scrolling back to top with scroll animation, changes it's text AND should focus on a form element.

Any suggestions?

```
$('.sign_in').click(function () {

    // IMPORTANT - This scrolls the page back to top if user clicks on '.sign_in' div - May need fixed as it flickers for some reason...
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 350); // NOTE: Set second number to '0' to eliminate flicker - however, doing this also eliminates scroll animation speed...

    // return false; // NOTE: Having 'return false;' stated here allows for smooth scrolling without flicker but disables the rest of the functions...

    // IMPORTANT - If/Else statement changes text on '.sign_in' div
    if ($(this).text() == 'REGISTER') {
        $(this).text('LOGIN');

        // IMPORTANT - This autofocuses on form element for 'Register' form
        $('.fname').focus();
    } else {
        $(this).text('REGISTER');

        // IMPORTANT - This autofocuses on form element for 'Login' form
        $('.uname').focus();
    }

    // IMPORTANT - This flips the form if user clicks on '.sign_in' div
    $('#formContainer').toggleClass('flipped');

    // return false; // NOTE: Having 'return false;' stated here allows all functions to run but causes flicker on scroll animation...
});
```

Comment: do you have an uploadable example? it's hard to tell whats wrong just by inspecting the code

Comment: I'll do my best to get a demo on jsfiddle...Give me a few minutes

Comment: Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/62k29xyf/ - Simply put, if you scroll down and click on the "LOGIN" tab in the fixed header, the animation works along with all other functions BUT, the animation of scroll flickers before it is performed.  If I add "return false;" in the either location specified in the above question, part of things work and other parts don't...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gcmj956d/1/ ?

Comment: or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gcmj956d/2/

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH Arun P Johny!  Your second iteration is literally perfect!  If you add that as an answer, I'll checkmark it as correct!

Comment: Also, just as a random question, does using "return;" mean the same things as "return false;" ?  I tried both, and both work, but I am curious as to the difference between the two

Comment: no they are not... just saying `return` will return undefined... which is the same as not having a return statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in setting focus to the input element, set it after the animation and it should be fine

```
$('.sign_in').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this), counter = 0;

    // IMPORTANT - This scrolls the page back to top if user clicks on '.sign_in' div - May need fixed as it flickers for some reason...    
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 350, function(){
        if(++counter>1){return;}

        // IMPORTANT - If/Else statement changes text on '.sign_in' div
        if ($this.text().toUpperCase().trim() == 'REGISTER') {
            $this.text('LOGIN');

            // IMPORTANT - This autofocuses on form element for 'Register' form
            $('.fname').focus();
        } else {
            $this.text('REGISTER');

            // IMPORTANT - This autofocuses on form element for 'Login' form
            $('.uname').focus();
        }
    }); // NOTE: Set second number to '0' to eliminate flicker - however, doing this also eliminates scroll animation speed...

    // IMPORTANT - This flips the form if user clicks on '.sign_in' div
    $('#formContainer').toggleClass('flipped');

    // return false; // NOTE: Having 'return false;' stated here allows for smooth scrolling without flicker but disables the rest of the functions...

    // return false; // NOTE: Having 'return false;' stated here allows all functions to run but causes flicker on scroll animation...
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gcmj956d/)

Comment: Thanks again Arun P Johny - I don't know how many hours I've spent trying to get this to work...

Comment: There does seem to be an issue with the flip effect in IE, but go figure right...it's IE, but that is a different area of concern and isn't stemming from this current problem (which is now solved).

Comment: the problem was setting the focus was bring the element into view causing the flickering effect then the animation was continuing

Comment: I had a feeling that might have been the root of the issue, I just couldn't put a finger on it.  Thanks for your help and explanation!